# Scala String Concatentation Problem

Tags: scala

This was a fairly hard bug to find in my code but once i found it i was surprised the compiler didn't catch it or understand why it was valid.

```
val my_string =
    "abc" +
    "def"
    "ghi"
```

The value of `my_string` ended up being `"abcdef"` since i missed the `+` sign after `"def"`.  Why didn't the compiler complain and what happened to `"ghi"`?

Comment: will now enclose multi-line strings in triple quotes to avoid future bugs

Comment: A common practice is to wrap all tokens of an expression inside parenthesis to avoid such issues, e.g., val my_string = (
  ... )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code is valid because `"ghi"` is a valid expression on its own.

If this is inside a function (and not followed by anything else) then `"ghi"` is the return value of that function. Otherwise it's just ignored (like if you'd written `42 + 23` on a line on its own).

Comment: it's being declared as an instance variable inside my class.  I guess you wouldn't be able to reference it, it would just execute and move on?

Comment: @Mark: Any expression in the class body is considered part of the constructor. So every time an instance of your class is created the expressions `"ghi"` is evaluated (which doesn't have any effect at all).

Comment: that's right! i remember reading that now / i appreciate it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

"ghi" is just an expression of type String, why should the compiler complain?

Comment: because in java it is not statment so it is logical to assume that compiler would fail if you came from java world

Comment: @yura: yes, but this is not Java, and you should not make the mistake of looking at Scala as Java with some "extensions". I find that one of the most useful mind shifts if you're learning Scala, is to understand that *everything* is just an expression that evaluates to something.